# Use alias in sequelize query wheres attribute?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

This is my sample code, my question is how to make 'cityName' to alias in query

```
const test = await test.findAll({
    where: { cityName: { $like: '%' + searchWord + '%' } },
    attributes: ['a', 'b']
})
```

sorry for my English skill
here is my additional description, I want to use parameters to replace 'cityName'

```
let NewCityName = 'something'

const test = await test.findAll({
    where: { NewCityName: { $like: '%' + searchWord + '%' } },
    attributes: ['a', 'b']
})
```

This code doesn't work, but it seems to help understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
I got an idea from the 'Operator Alias' section of the Sequelize API Reference

```
const test = {
  where: { cityName: { $like: '%' + searchWord + '%' } }
}

const test = await test.findAll({
  test,
  attributes: ['a', 'b']
})
```

Solved by aliasing the whole of 'where'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible. Try this.

```
const test = await test.findAll({
where: { cityName: { $like: '%' + searchWord + '%' } },
attributes: ['id',['cityName', 'city']]
})
```

Here `cityName` will be aliased to `city`

Comment: using `$like` is deprecated, use `[Op.like]: %${searchword}%` instead.

Comment: Only if you are using >=v5